# How do I get a block of Python Pandas .loc lines to reference the original dataframe rather than running in order on top of one another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, overwrite, pandas-loc

In the example below (df name 'statement', column name 'product'), I want product 1 to be changed to product 2.  I achieve this on the first line, but then the second line changes it from product 2 to product 18. Later, it changes from product 18 to product 13. How to perform all the loc operations given below in parallel. Instead of performing one after the other.

Example:

```
statement.loc[statement['product'] == 1, 'product'] = 2
statement.loc[statement['product'] == 2, 'product'] = 18
statement.loc[statement['product'] == 18, 'product'] = 13
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) instead of loc filtering to do this

```
mappings = {1:2, 2:18, 18:13}
statement['product'] = statement['product'].replace(mappings)
```